# ASP.NET PageHandlerFactory (.html files)

Tags: asp.net

I have added the lines to the web.config to make .html files handled by the pagehandlerfactory - but it isn't working when I publish the site to a live web host. It works on my development box (Not using IIS), but I don't have any other options on my live to add anything... It's a shared hosting environment.

What should I try to do? I don't get any errors, so I know it can't be because of the root web.config overwriting.

```
            <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        </assemblies>
        <buildProviders>
            <add extension=".html" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
        </buildProviders>
    </compilation>

        <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.mvc" validate="false" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.html" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
```

Then in the HTML page...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="System.Web.UI.Page" %>
```

...
    <% Response.Write("Testing. This is content written by ASP.NET."); %>

Comment: can you show the lines you added, and elaborate on what you mean "is not working"?

Comment: Information requested posted below.

Comment: Added it to the original question. Forgive me, a little new to stackoverflow in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely problem is that IIS isn't configured to route requests for .html files through ASP.NET.

Check your web site's IIS properties, Home Directory Tab, Configuration... button, Mappings tab.

At the top you'll see a list of file extensions and what the handler for that extension is.  Anything that's not in that list will just be served as a flat file, which is more efficient on heavy load rather than loading the ASP.NET environment only to then just write a file out to the response.

So the solution is basically just to add .html/.htm to the list, and copy the settings from one of the other ones like .aspx

The reason I suspect this worked on your development machine is that you ran the website from the debugger rather than through IIS.  The debugger processes all requests, rather than the more complicated handling of IIS.

Note that this is all IIS 6 and below information -- things are a bit different if you're on IIS 7.

Comment: I cannot access this kind of thing. It is a shared hosting environment.

Comment: Do your URLS *have* to be .html?  Can they be something weird like .axd?

Comment: If you don't have control over the hosting environment, then there's probably no way you'll be able to have special handling for html files.  But if you can just make all your links for http://mysite/myfile.axd, you'll be fine since .axd will already be mapped to ASP.NET by default in IIS

Comment: (do your urls have to be .html?)

. . . (more ellipses in 30 seconds.)

. . . 

. . .

...no.